# Two different pages with reportlab SimpleDocTemplate and Django

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I'm using django and generating reports following [this example](http://eric.sau.pe/reportlab-and-django-part-3-paragraphs-and-tables/), I need to generate a last page but without headers or footers and different content.

I'm trying to do this:

```
def print_example(self):
    buffer = self.buffer
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
                            rightMargin=72,
                            leftMargin=72,
                            topMargin=72,
                            bottomMargin=72,
                            pagesize=self.pagesize)

    elements = []
    elements.append(Paragraph('Content for all pages'), my_custom_style)
    # ...

    doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=self._header_footer, onLaterPages=self._header_footer,
                  canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)

    doc2 = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
                        rightMargin=72,
                        leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,
                        bottomMargin=72,
                        pagesize=self.pagesize)

    elements2 = []
    elements2.append(Paragraph('Content for the last page only'), my_custom_style)

    doc2.build(elements2, canvasmaker=NumberedCanvas)


    # Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    return pdf
```

Then only the last content appears and previous content dissapears.

How can I generate the last page with different content?

Comment: `doc` and `doc2` are using the same buffer. This means when you do `doc2.build` you are probably overwriting the previous build in the buffer. Try either including the last paragraph in with the list of elements you use for the build or storing the results of the build in a variable before the next build. It is a little unclear as to how you are deciding when to show the content for the last page only, so your fix will depend on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using `SimpleDocTemplate` but you can achieve this by using `BaseDocTemplate` and defining your own templates.

#### Basic example

```
from reportlab.platypus import PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate, NextPageTemplate, PageBreak

def headerFooterLayout(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setPageSize(self.pagesize)
    # add header/footer
    canvas.restoreState()

def emptyLayout(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()
    canvas.setPageSize(self.pagesize)
    canvas.restoreState()

pHeight, pWidth = self.pagesize
myFrame = Frame(0, 0, pHeight, pWidth, id='myFrame')

headerFooterTemplate = PageTemplate(id='headerFooterTemplate',
                                    frames=[myFrame],
                                    onPage=headerFooterLayout)

emptyTemplate = PageTemplate(id='emptyTemplate',
                             frames=[myFrame],
                             onPage=emptyLayout)

elements = []
elements.append(Paragraph('blah', style))
elements.append(NextPageTemplate('emptyTemplate'))
elements.append(PageBreak())
elements.append(Paragraph('last page', style))

doc = BaseDocTemplate(buffer,
                      rightMargin=72,
                      leftMargin=72,
                      topMargin=72,
                      bottomMargin=72)

doc.addPageTemplates([headerFooterTemplate, emptyTemplate])

doc.build(elements)
```

It's been quite a while since I used this so there may well be some issues but comment if something doesn't work.

This is all in the [user guide](http://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) but can be hard to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, however there is a typo addPageTemplates instead addPageTemplates

Comment: @BraulioSoncco what typo?